# How can I reset room db database schema if I don't want to increment the version?

Tags: android, android-room, roomdb

My app is getting the following error:

> Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.

I don't want to increase the version since the app I'm developing is not yet released. What should I do to prevent this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [clear the app data](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=android%20clear%20app%20data) after changing the schema.

Comment: This will clear all of the app data, be it shared preferences or other cached / data files. OP wants to clear/reset Room DB.

Comment: But it's safer to clear everything. Clearly only the database puts your app into a state that the user would never experience.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling but it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the existing data in the Room DB, you can clear the tables like this:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    yourRoomDBInstance.clearAllTables()
}
```